# Neighborhood of zero in the weak star topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I'm trying to understand why in case of infinite dimensional normed space $X$ any neighborhood of zero in the $*$-weak topology contains an infinite dimensional linear subspace.

Here is a proof of the similar statement for the weak topology on $X$ from Rudin's *Functional analysis* book:

[image]

I think that it may also work in case of the *-weak topology and trying to modify it but there are some unclear moments for me.

- Zero in $X^*$ is just an identically zero functional $\lambda \equiv 0$ and its neighborhood consists of linear functionals with small operator norms, but I don't understand how an analogue of subset $V$ from Rudin's proof will look like in my case?
- Suppose that we already has $V$. Than $V \supset N = \{\lambda\colon \lambda(x_1) = \ldots = \lambda(x_n) = 0\}$, so we have a map $\varphi\colon X^*\to\mathbb{C}^n$ that sends $\lambda$ to $(\lambda(x_1),\ldots,\lambda(x_n))$. Why is it true that $\mbox{dim}X^* \leq \mbox{dim}N + \mbox{dim}\mathbb{C}^n = \mbox{dim}N + n$? Looks like a simple question but I can't see is it true for arbitrarily map $f \colon X \to Y$ that $\mbox{dim}X \leq \mbox{dim Ker}f + \mbox{dim Im}f$?

So, please help me to modify proof for $X^*$ and $*$-weak topology or suggest more simple way to understand that problem if it exists. I would be very appreciative for any help.

Comment: We have $\mbox{dim}X^* \leq \mbox{dim}N + \mbox{dim}\mathbb{C}^n = \mbox{dim}N + n$ essentially because the dimension of the range of $\phi$ does not exceed $n$.  That is, $\phi$ may not be full-rank.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a Banach space. You may embed $E$ into $E^{**}$ by $\kappa_E \colon E\to E^{**}$ given by 
$$\langle \kappa_E x,f\rangle = \langle f,x\rangle \quad (x\in E, f\in E^*).$$
Then you may copy the proof almost verbatim by replacing $X$ with $E^*$ (and so $X^{*}$ with $E^{**}$).